# Restrictions of using Social framework for a Twitter app?

Tags: ios, twitter, social-framework, acaccount

I'm looking into making a new app which integrates heavily with Twitter, and I'm trying to find out if the Accounts and Social framework is capable of that.

It's worked in the past for basic calls, but it's not stated anywhere what its limits are - can it be used for a full-blown Twitter app?

Integrating with Twitter manually, I know involves asking the user to sign in, and means a cap of 100k tokens. Are there any caveats of using the Social framework instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the API without users signing in to view most everything. Read the docs: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search